# CPUID family/model number for AMD processors

Tags: x86, amd-processor, cpuid

I'd like to use CPUID (eax=1) to check for a particular range of AMD CPU's, in particular, the Bulldozer line, but I can't seem to find any information online as to what the model number range of these CPU's are. That said, I can get a decent range of Intel CPU's here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-and-processor-identification-with-cpuid-model-and-family-numbers

I do know that I need to read bits 19:16 and 7:4 to get the model id.

Comment: here are CPUID dumps of a lot of CPUs: http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/

Comment: Thanks. That pretty much got me all the information I was looking for. I'm pretty sure I just need to make exceptions for all AMD 15h family CPU's in my case.